# Complement of NP-complete can be in NP

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, np

Here are a couple of questions I struggle with.  (We use $A'$ to denote the complement of the problem $A$.)

1. A problem $A$ is NP-complete if and only if $A'$ is in NP?
2. A class problem $A$ is NP-Complete iff $A'$ is in NP?  (Is there any difference between these two?)

I got this claim to be true that

> If there is an NP-complete language $L$ whose complement is in NP, then the complement of any language in NP is in NP.

And this claim also to be true:

> $A$ is NP-hard iff $A'$ is coNP−hard

Then is the upper claim also true?

Comment: The claim is false. Consider $A = \emptyset$.

Comment: I havenot got. If A=phi , then A and A' both in phi . right?

Comment: then how this claim is true that "If there is an NP-complete language L whose complement is in NP, then the complement of any language in NP is in NP"

Comment: @Srestha The empty set (`\emptyset`, $\emptyset$) is not NP-complete, nor is its complement.

Comment: I answered as much of your question as I could understand (below) but I don't know what you mean by "a class problem" or "the upper claim".

Comment: @DavidRicherby then can u tell this claim is also true or not-"If there is an NP-complete language  whose complement is in NP, then the complement of any language in NP is in NP."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A problem $A$ is NP-complete if and only if $A'$ is in NP?

This is false. Take $A'=\emptyset$: then we have $A'\in\mathrm{NP}$ but $A=\Sigma^*$ is not $\mathrm{NP}$-complete.

> If there is an NP-complete language $L$ whose complement is in NP, then the complement of any language in NP is in NP.

This follows from the following three facts, which you should attempt to prove yourself.

1. The complement of an $\text{NP}$-complete problem is $\text{co-NP}$-complete;
2. if any $\text{co-NP}$-complete problem is in a class $\mathcal{C}$ that is closed under polynomial-time reductions, then every $\text{co-NP}\subseteq\mathcal{C}$;
3. $\text{NP}$ is closed under polynomial-time reductions.